# nested for loop to check if first letter of each string in 2d array is a consonant in c

Tags: arrays, c, string, for-loop

i'm a beginner to programming and I'm running into a problem. I think that this is quite basic but I have looked around everywhere and can't find a solution (probably because of my own lack of understanding). This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char inputString[999];
    char inputArray[99][99]; 
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    fgets(inputString, sizeof inputString, stdin);
    for(int i = 0; i <= (strlen(inputString)); i++) {
        if(inputString[i] == ' ' || inputString[i] == '\0') {
            inputArray[a][b] = '\0';
            a++;  
            b = 0;    
        } 
        else {
            inputArray[a][b] = inputString[i];
            b++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i][0] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 99; j++) {
            iif (inputArray[i][0] == 'a' || inputArray[i][0] == 'e' || inputArray[i][0] == 'i' || inputArray[i][0] == 'o' || inputArray[i][0] == 'u' ||
                inputArray[i][0] == 'A' || inputArray[i][0] == 'E' || inputArray[i][0] == 'I' || inputArray[i][0] == 'O' || inputArray[i][0] == 'U') {
                if (inputArray[i][j] == '.') {
                    inputArray[i][j] = '\0';
                    if (inputArray[i][j] == '\0') {
                        inputArray[i][j] = 'm';
                        inputArray[i][j + 1] = 'o';
                        inputArray[i][j + 2] = 'o';
                        inputArray[i][j + 3] = '.';
                        inputArray[i][j + 4] = '\0';
                        i++;
                        j = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if (inputArray[i][j] == ',') {
                    inputArray[i][j] = '\0';
                    if (inputArray[i][j] == '\0') {
                        inputArray[i][j] = 'm';
                        inputArray[i][j + 1] = 'o';
                        inputArray[i][j + 2] = 'o';
                        inputArray[i][j + 3] = ',';
                        inputArray[i][j + 4] = '\0';
                        i++;
                        j = 0;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (inputArray[i][j] == '\0') {
                        inputArray[i][j] = 'm';
                        inputArray[i][j + 1] = 'o';
                        inputArray[i][j + 2] = 'o';
                        inputArray[i][j + 3] = '\0';
                        i++;
                        j = 0;
                    }
                }
            } 
            else if (inputArray[i][0] != 'a' || inputArray[i][0] != 'e' || inputArray[i][0] != 'i' || inputArray[i][0] != 'o' || inputArray[i][0] != 'u' ||
                    inputArray[i][0] != 'A' || inputArray[i][0] != 'E' || inputArray[i][0] != 'I' || inputArray[i][0] != 'O' || inputArray[i][0] != 'U' || inputArray[i][0] != '\0') {
                printf("a");
                i++;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
        printf("%s ", inputArray[i]);
        if (inputArray[i][0] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Essentially I'm trying to input a string, separate them into words using a 2-D array, and then check if the first letters of each string in that array is a consonant or a vowel.
I'm using printf("a"); to test if my code works, but when i run the program and input something like "yo", this is the output:

```
yo
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaayo
```

The letter "a" is printed 99 times, which is as many times as the inner for loop is ran, so i'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that the first element of every string in the array is also not a vowel and maybe it's a null character, so I tried adding if (inputArray[i][0] == '\0') { (like in the code), but it still doesn't work.

I'd really appreciate if you guys can help me out

EDIT: I changed the code a bit to make it more readable (thanks Benjamin Maurer!), but essentially what I'm trying to do in the first if statement is add "moo" to the end of a word if it starts with a vowel.

Answer (score 0):

Your code starts normal, but why did you then switch from array notation to this absolute madness in the second loop with pointer dereferences? I'm not even going to try to understand that code, bc. it's unreadable.

According to your description, each of `inputArray[i]` is a string. So checking if `inputArray[i][0]` is a consontant/vowel should suffice, no?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// ...Read input...

for (int i = 0; i < 99; ++i) {
    if (isalpha(inputArray[i][0])) {
        char c = toupper(inputArray[i][0]);
        switch (c) {
            // Intentional fallthroughs
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
                puts("is vowel!");
                break;

            default:
                puts("is consonant");
        }
    }
}
```

Both `isalpha` and `toupper` are from `ctype.h`.
[islapha](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) checks whether the argument is an alphabetic latin character (a letter).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, I don't think I can use switch cases as my course hasn't taught that yet, so I'm trying to do it with if statements.

Comment: OK, but same thing in the end: `if (c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c =='I'....` and so on and so forth. The `default` case becomes an `else` branch.